# Bash Script store cat output in variable and then echo it

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to store a cat output into a variable and then trying to echo it. and then I would like to kill the process.

```
#!/bin/bash

var = $(cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)

echo $var
sudo kill -QUIT $var
```

Please if anyone can tell where I am going wrong

Comment: Are you missing slash from begin of file name?

Comment: Don't put space around `=`. It should be `var=$(cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)`. Also provide valid path.

Comment: @sat `tmp/pids/unicorn.pid` *is* a valid path; it might not be the right path, but that isn't relevant to this question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Variable assignments in bash should not have any spaces before or after the equal sign. It should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)
echo "$var"
```

Which can be written more idiomatically as

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(< tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)
echo "$var"
```

Comment: +1 This saved my day: "Variable assignments in bash should not have any spaces before or after the equal sign"