# How to pass authorization key in shell script curl command without header

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, sh, rsa, cat

In a shell script, I need to pull a private key from a `.pem` file. When I set my `AUTORIZATION` variable to the path, the variable is only the filepath string, not the actual filepath.

If I change my `AUTHORIZATION` variable to `cat <FILE_PATH>` it imports the header and footer i.e. `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY... END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

How do I pull out the RSA key without the header and footer?

```
CLUSTER=standalone
TENANT=climate
NAMESPACE=integration_test
AUTHORIZATION=$REPO_ROOT/pulsar/tls/broker/broker.key.pem

echo $AUTHORIZATION

# Create tenant
curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cat` to get the output from the file location and then stored that to the variable

```
AUTHORIZATION=$(cat $REPO_ROOT/pulsar/tls/broker/broker.key.pem)
```

[You may refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192725/bash-script-store-cat-output-in-variable-and-then-echo-it)